# Can I apply BABYLON textures and materials to vertices of a ground?

Tags: reflection, vertices, babylonjs

I'm new in babylon.js and trying to create a dynamic water surface.

I succeeded in creating waves on a flat surface (using a ground and updateVerticesData).

What i need now is doing reflections (thought about reflection textures) and refractions (tought about mirrors).
Both are done by babylon by using planes but my surface is not flat but dynamic.

Can I apply the correct reflections and refractions to the vertices or to the triangles componing my ground ?

Is it ok to do that in a realtime rendering ?

Thanks for any suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

Forgive my lack of details and research.

I succeed by using Babylon.waterMaterial : https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#1SLLOJ#481.

Indeed, using updateVerticesData and waterMaterial both is ok.